# Accessing external files on network directories when deployed with microservice Jar file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have a microservice app that does image processing with ImageJ which I have created a microservice using spring boot.

Often the image I am trying to load is coming from a samba share mapped to a directory like p:/

I have an issue that is ***ONLY*** happening when I execute the spring boot app as a JAR directly.  If I execute it directly from STS using the tool executors it works fine.  As well, the file is readable, viewable etc.

```
File f = new File("P:\\Stamps\\_Temp\\Img001.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
```

This will result in

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308) ~[na:na]
```

For debugging purposes I had it print out the .exist() and .canRead() - when executed in STS (Eclipse) these both return true, however from the JAR it will return false.  More over if I try to access the image *directly* from a local folder (say c:\my-images) it works fine. So my assumption is there is some thing restricting access to these Network shared files when accessed from within a Jar (only).

I have not been able to find any reference information via searches to this on the usage of File so I am wondering if there is a spring boot configuration that is blocking this access (mainfest setting etc), or if it is a restriction of executing class byte-code from within a JAR?

Comment: I should add most of the discussion around the "Can't read input file!" have been about improper reference to the file object.  I can state that if I mount the directory from the samba share using "subst" for example ("subst k: //my-server/path-to/images/Img001.jpg") this *DOES* work from the JAR.  I currently have P: drive mapped using Windows 10 standard folder explorer, browse, "map network drive".

Comment: does that happen to all files or that particular file only?

Comment: All files mapped this way.  I also tried leveraging the "Files" object in nio to check if it had some better "navigation" logic with         
    
 File f = ResourceUtils.getFile(filename);
    Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filename);
    System.out.println("exists?" + Files.exists(p, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));   
 
 
no avail - it is still false for Windows mapped folders

Comment: Similiar issue seen many years ago with JBoss - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242388?_sscc=t no real solution listed.

Comment: Based on further reading it looks like "File[] files = File.listRoots();" will only report drives that are physical disks or were mapped with "subst" when accessed from a JAR created via spring-boot.  Mapped network drives are not accessible in this way.   Curiously enough when executed within Eclipse it does list them all (again I am assuming it is not running within a JAR but as an exploded classpath.

Answer (score 1):

So networked Mapped Drives in Windows can be accessed if you track back to the remote name and replace that drive letter with the appropriate mapping name.  This thread covers an example where they do that: https://gist.github.com/digulla/31eed31c7ead29ffc7a30aaf87131def they key here is to replace the "P:" with "\server\path"

Again does not explain why this fails via Jar access vs. class exploded access, but at least it covers a workaround.  For my use I might just simply use a mapping file since while I use the Network Mapping, I do not know how common this would be for other users and asking them to set some configuration in application.properties does not seem ridiculous for those cases.  Still if anyone has insights into WHY we get different behavior inside and outside the Jar execution I'd be curious (or whether there is some spring-boot property in the manifest that needs to be set)